# Can't figure out how to use this lightbox component i found online

Tags: reactjs

So, I've been learning React for a while and am making a website. I want to include a lightbox that has a gallery of thumbnail images, and when you click on one it magnifies it.

I found this thread https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/8ubdsn/does_anyone_know_of_a_simple_image_gallery/.

Lots of the ones linked there are like what I want, but I can't seem to get them working. For instance, the first one mentioned there, https://github.com/benhowell/react-grid-gallery . It has a "Quick and dirty start" option, with this code.

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Gallery from 'react-grid-gallery';

const IMAGES =
[{
        src: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8817/28973449265_07e3aa5d2e_b.jpg",
        thumbnail: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8817/28973449265_07e3aa5d2e_n.jpg",
        thumbnailWidth: 320,
        thumbnailHeight: 174,
        isSelected: true,
        caption: "After Rain (Jeshu John - designerspics.com)"
},
{
        src: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8356/28897120681_3b2c0f43e0_b.jpg",
        thumbnail: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8356/28897120681_3b2c0f43e0_n.jpg",
        thumbnailWidth: 320,
        thumbnailHeight: 212,
        tags: [{value: "Ocean", title: "Ocean"}, {value: "People", title: "People"}],
        caption: "Boats (Jeshu John - designerspics.com)"
},

{
        src: "https://c4.staticflickr.com/9/8887/28897124891_98c4fdd82b_b.jpg",
        thumbnail: "https://c4.staticflickr.com/9/8887/28897124891_98c4fdd82b_n.jpg",
        thumbnailWidth: 320,
        thumbnailHeight: 212
}]

render(
        <Gallery images={IMAGES}/>,
        document.getElementById('example-0')
);
```

Now, normally when I make a component, it looks something like this,

```
export default class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
            <div>
                  <img src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/749263/original.jpg"/>
            </div>

            )
        }
}
```

So then I can just include it wherever I want in my main App.js file or wherever by importing and typing `<ExampleComponent />` .

So if I was to turn the "Quick and Dirty" code into a component that I can use in my other files, how do I do it? Like, I don't know where const IMAGES should go, or where render/return should go.

I just want to be able to use the component and change the image urls to the ones I want. I don't need to do anything fancy with it for now.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `Gallery` component is a component on it's own, so you can just directly use it in your `App` when necessary. If you do want to make it it's own component with the images included following your format than you can do something like this.

```
export default class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {

  // variable declaration will be placed in the constructor.
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.IMAGES =
      [{
        src: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8817/28973449265_07e3aa5d2e_b.jpg",
        thumbnail: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8817/28973449265_07e3aa5d2e_n.jpg",
        thumbnailWidth: 320,
        thumbnailHeight: 174,
        isSelected: true,
        caption: "After Rain (Jeshu John - designerspics.com)"
      },
      {
        src: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8356/28897120681_3b2c0f43e0_b.jpg",
        thumbnail: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8356/28897120681_3b2c0f43e0_n.jpg",
        thumbnailWidth: 320,
        thumbnailHeight: 212,
        tags: [{value: "Ocean", title: "Ocean"}, {value: "People", title: "People"}],
        caption: "Boats (Jeshu John - designerspics.com)"
      },
      {
        src: "https://c4.staticflickr.com/9/8887/28897124891_98c4fdd82b_b.jpg",
        thumbnail: "https://c4.staticflickr.com/9/8887/28897124891_98c4fdd82b_n.jpg",
        thumbnailWidth: 320,
        thumbnailHeight: 212
      }]; 
  }

  //You can than use your variable using this.variableName in your render method.
  render() {
    return (
      <Gallery images={this.IMAGES}/>
    )
  }
}
```

Or if you would like a more readable approach, It is not necessary to use a `Class` component in your case. You can use a `Function` component like this:

```
const exampleComponent = () => {
  const IMAGES =
    [{
      src: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8817/28973449265_07e3aa5d2e_b.jpg",
      thumbnail: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8817/28973449265_07e3aa5d2e_n.jpg",
        thumbnailWidth: 320,
        thumbnailHeight: 174,
        isSelected: true,
        caption: "After Rain (Jeshu John - designerspics.com)"
    },
    {
      src: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8356/28897120681_3b2c0f43e0_b.jpg",
      thumbnail: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8356/28897120681_3b2c0f43e0_n.jpg",
        thumbnailWidth: 320,
        thumbnailHeight: 212,
        tags: [{value: "Ocean", title: "Ocean"}, {value: "People", title: "People"}],
        caption: "Boats (Jeshu John - designerspics.com)"
    },
    {
      src: "https://c4.staticflickr.com/9/8887/28897124891_98c4fdd82b_b.jpg",
      thumbnail: "https://c4.staticflickr.com/9/8887/28897124891_98c4fdd82b_n.jpg",
        thumbnailWidth: 320,
        thumbnailHeight: 212
    }];

  return (
    <Gallery images={IMAGES} />
  )
}
```

Comment: Looks great, thanks Luze. Just in work now but I’ll try this when I’m home.

Comment: Great, let me know if it works or if you need more guidance, I’ll gladly help.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! Now I can use the lightbox as I wanted to.

Comment: Great, glad I could help, can you please mark my question as “accepted answer” and give it an upvote? That would help me too to get some reputation for it.

Comment: I would love to, but unfortunately it seems because I have below 15 reputation, I can’t.